# change-username.php renames username to blank in the database

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

My aim is to create a user dashboard where the user can update his/her details like username, password and email.

The code below is from reset-password.php (which actually works). I tried to edit it to change Username and Email. But first I need to make it work properly.

I get no errors when clicking on the submit button but it renames the original username to blank. I can't find the problem. I'm new to this type of PHP (I've learnt the very simple procedural type). Please help.

```
<?php
*// Initialize the session*
session_start();
*// Check if the user is logged in, otherwise redirect to login page*
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
header("location: login.php");
exit;
}
*// Include config file*
require_once "config.php";

*// Define variables and initialize with empty values*
$new_username = "";
$new_username_err = "";

*// Processing form data when form is submitted*
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

*// Validate new Username*
if(empty(trim($_POST["new_username"]))){
    $new_username_err = "Please enter a new username.";     
}

*// Check input errors before updating the database*
if(empty($new_username_err)){
    *// Prepare an update statement*
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET username = ? WHERE id = ?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        *// Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters*
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $param_username, $param_id);

        *// Set parameters*
        $param_username = $new_username;
        $param_id = $_SESSION["id"];

        *// Attempt to execute the prepared statement*
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            *// Username updated successfully. Destroy the session, and redirect to login page*
            session_destroy();
            header("location: change-username-success.php");
            exit();
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }

    *// Close statement*
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

*// Close connection*
mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

My Form codes:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">

                <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($new_username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                    <input type="text" name="new_username" placeholder="New Username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $new_username; ?>">
                    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $new_username_err; ?></span>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit">
                    <a class="btn" href="userpage.php"><i class="fas fa-ban"></i>Cancel</a>
                </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: You set `$param_username = $new_username` but never assign anything to `$new_username` before that.

Comment: @NigelRen Thank You. I forgot to add : 

 `else{
        $new_username = trim($_POST["new_username"]);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You are binding params before you are assigning them:

```
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $param_username, $param_id);

    *// Set parameters*
    $param_username = $new_username;
    $param_id = $_SESSION["id"];
```

Put the block with binding after assignment:

```
    *// Set parameters*
    $param_username = $new_username;
    $param_id = $_SESSION["id"];

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $param_username, $param_id);
```

Comment: No. It did not work.
This code was missing:

`else 
{ $new_username = trim($_POST["new_username"]);
 }`